# Is there a way to compile/save data from an excel application used by multiple users in a central database?

Tags: python, excel, vba, database, ms-access

I am developing an application using MS Excel and VBA to process data and visualize the results. This application will be released and used by multiple users. The excel file is not a shared workbook, instead, the user can use the application independently with their own data.

My question is: How can I compile and save the data processed by each of the user to a central database so that it can be used for later analyses, such as how many records have been processed with the application by one particular user, or calculate the statistical summary of a particular feature of all data processed by all users.

I've tried to write a VBA so that when the user click on "Save" in Excel, it will dump the data into a MS Access saved into a shared drive that can only be accessed when the user connects to corporate VPN. Therefore, the issues are that if VPN is not connected, the data is not dumped into the database. Additionally, the application will also be released to an offshore team who do not have the access to the local shared drive so how may I get the data from them?

Is there a better way to do this job with VBA or Python? Thanks.

Comment: This is a connectivity problem, unrelated to coding. You need to find a location where everybody can dump files. Then there are multiple ways by which the dumping can be arranged and multiple ways by which dumped files can be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.  You can export data from Excel to MS Access, but as you have experienced and described, that is not a great option.  Do you have access to SQL Server?  If so, here are two options for you to consider.

```
Sub UpdateTable()

    Dim cnn As Object
    Dim wbkOpen As Workbook
    Dim objfl As Variant
    Dim rngName As Range
    Workbooks.Open "C:\you_path_here\excelfile.xls"
    Set wbkOpen = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Set rngName = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToLeft).End(xlDown))
    rngName.Name = "TempRange"
    strFileName = wbkOpen.FullName
    Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"";"
    nSQL = "INSERT INTO [odbc;Driver={SQL Server};Server=your_server_name;Database=[Northwind].[dbo].[TBL]]"
    nJOIN = " SELECT * from [TempRange]"
    cnn.Execute nSQL & nJOIN
    MsgBox "Uploaded Successfully"
    wbkOpen.Close
    Set wbkOpen = Nothing
    
End Sub

Sub InsertInto()

'Declare some variables
Dim cnn As adodb.Connection
Dim cmd As adodb.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set cnn = New adodb.Connection

'Set the connection string
cnn.ConnectionString = "your_server_name;Database=your_db_name;Trusted_Connection=True;"

'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New adodb.Command

'Open the connection
cnn.Open
'Associate the command with the connection
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

'Tell the Command we are giving it a bit of SQL to run, not a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Create the SQL
strSQL = "UPDATE TBL SET some_date = 2021-01-01 WHERE employeeID = 1"

'Pass the SQL to the Command object
cmd.CommandText = strSQL

'Open the Connection to the database
cnn.Open

'Execute the bit of SQL to update the database
cmd.Execute

'Close the connection again
cnn.Close

'Remove the objects
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

End Sub
```